# render Visual Composer shortcodes onto page

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, visual-composer

I am trying to `echo` visual composer `shortcodes` onto a page.

I've tried both methods below, but they don't work:

**functions.php:**

**Method 1**

```
/*
 * add shortcode file
 */
function include_file($atts) {
    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'slug' => 'NULL',
    ), $atts );

    if($slug != 'NULL'){
        ob_start();
        get_template_part($a['slug']);
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
}
add_shortcode('include', 'include_file');
```

**Method 2**

```
function someshortocode_callback( $atts = array(), $content = null ) {

    $output = "[vc_section full_width=\"stretch_row\" css=\".vc_custom_1499155244783{padding-top: 8vh !important;padding-bottom: 5vh !important;background-color: #f7f7f7 !important;}\"][vc_row 0=\"\"][vc_column offset=\"vc_col-lg-offset-3 vc_col-lg-6 vc_col-md-offset-3 vc_col-md-6\"][/vc_column][/vc_row][/vc_section]";
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode('someshortocode', 'someshortocode_callback');
```

**file_rendering_vc_shortcodes.php:**

**Method 1**

```
<?php if ( is_plugin_active( 'js_composer/js_composer.php' ) ) {
    wc_print_notice('js_composer plugin ACTIVE', 'notice');
    echo do_shortcode('[include slug="vc_templates/shop-page"]');
}; ?>
```

**Result**

- js_composer plugin ACTIVE
- shortcode is on page with parentheses as is

**Method 2**

```
<?php $post = get_post();

if ( $post && preg_match( '/vc_row/', $post->post_content ) ) {
// Visual composer works on current page/post
    wc_print_notice('VC ON', 'notice');
    echo add_shortcode('someshortocode', 'someshortocode_callback');
} else {
    wc_print_notice('VC OFF', 'notice');
    //echo do_shortcode('[include slug="vc_templates/shop-page"]');
}; ?>
```

**Result**

- VC OFF (obviously, since the `vc_row` in shortcode is not there)
- shortcode is NOT on page

**shop-page.php**

```
<?php
/**
Template Name:  Shop Page in theme
Preview Image:  #
Descriptions:   #
 * [vc_row][vc_column][/vc_column][/vc_row]
 */
?>
[vc_section full_width="stretch_row" css=".vc_custom_1499155244783{padding-top: 8vh !important;padding-bottom: 5vh !important;background-color: #f7f7f7 !important;}"][vc_row 0=""][vc_column offset="vc_col-lg-offset-3 vc_col-lg-6 vc_col-md-offset-3 vc_col-md-6"][/vc_column][/vc_row][/vc_section]
```

Is it possible to render `vc shortcodes` on page, and if so, how is it done?

Answer (score 2):

Use the:

```
WPBMap::addAllMappedShortcodes();
```

then as usual `do_shortcode($content);`

In short, page builder due to performance doesn't register shortcodes unless it isn't required.

If your element is registered by `vc_map` or `vc_lean_map` then no need to use `add_shortcode` function, you can do everything just by using `WPBMap::addAllMappedShortcodes();` it is will call an shortcode class callback during the rendering process and then shortcode template.

Comment: you are my hero tonight!  thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding **Method 2.**

You have to use `do_shortcode()` in your shortcode function.

```
function someshortocode_callback( $atts = array(), $content = null ) {
    $output = '[vc_section full_width="stretch_row" css=".vc_custom_1499155244783{padding-top: 8vh !important;padding-bottom: 5vh !important;background-color: #f7f7f7 !important;}"][vc_row 0=""][vc_column offset="vc_col-lg-offset-3 vc_col-lg-6 vc_col-md-offset-3 vc_col-md-6"]column text[/vc_column][/vc_row][/vc_section]';

    return do_shortcode( $output );
}

add_shortcode( 'someshortocode', 'someshortocode_callback' );
```

Working example on my test site: http://test.kagg.eu/46083958-2/

Page contains only `[someshortocode]`. Code above is added to `functions.php`.

In your code for **Method 2** there is another error: line

```
echo add_shortcode('someshortocode', 'someshortocode_callback');
```

cannot work, as `add_shortcode()` returns nothing. This code should be as follows:

```
<?php $post = get_post();

if ( $post && preg_match( '/vc_row/', $post->post_content ) ) {
// Visual composer works on current page/post
    wc_print_notice('VC ON', 'notice');
} else {
    wc_print_notice('VC OFF', 'notice');
    add_shortcode('someshortocode', 'someshortocode_callback');
    echo do_shortcode('[someshortocode]');
}; ?>
```

Comment: No, page contains usual text: [someshortcode]. Please see the picture: http://take.ms/lLMdL

Comment: Code in my answer contains do_shortcode(). Please pay attention to line 4: return do_shortcode( $output );

Comment: I saw it all.... Just that I am trying to get it to work programmatically... Please read my question carefully.

Comment: I read your question carefully. In your Method 2 there are 2 errors: 1) you do not use do_shortcode() in someshortocode_callback, 2) line "echo add_shortcode('someshortocode', 'someshortocode_callback');" cannot work, as add_shortcode returns nothing.

Comment: I have extended the answer with your code for Method 2 corrected.

Comment: I fixed the errors you mentioned...still on page `echo do_shortcode('someshortocode')` & `echo do_shortcode('[someshortocode]');` yield nothing. And the main issue is how to programmatically `echo` the `shortcode`

Comment: I dont know on what page do you try to implement this code. I have created Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. An empty page is created with own Template: https://monosnap.com/file/yV2I0J6d4YyBmil2w1gYPoM4NCLcD8 Template file 46083958-3.php is as follows: http://take.ms/hciBL Result your can see on the page: http://test.kagg.eu/46083958-3/ Everything works.

Comment: I am trying to implement this on `woocommerce` shop page

Comment: As you can see, my code works. Why it doesn't work on WooCommerce shop page, it is another question, for which it has to be provided the full code of your WooCommerce archive page.